# Grails integration test and sessionFactory.currentSession

Tags: grails

Process that loads data from a remote server, triggered by a REST call. The integration test fails with:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'currentSession' on null object
```

The loads a lot of data, so calls flush every few hundred records loaded:

```
protected cleanUpGorm() {
    def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
    session.flush()
    session.clear()
}
```

As noted the session factory is not loaded. This is a 'helper groovy class' - neither service or controller. Do I have to now pass sessionFactory as per GrailsApplication?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with injection "sessionFactory" bean into regular groovy class.
It should be accessible using the following code:

```
ApplicationContext context = (ApplicationContext) ServletContextHolder.getServletContext().getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT);
SessionFactory sessionFactory = context.getBean('sessionFactory')
Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
```

Another technique for fetching the current session can be using grails utility class:

```
Session session = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession()
```

or

```
Session session = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().session
```

Comment: unfortunately, you are talking oranges and lemons with retrieving the session via the grails utility class. `WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().session` is not a relative of `org.hibernate.session`.   `GrailsHttpSession` is an inheritor from a different family of classes.  As such, using `def session = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().session` will not allow you to perform such requests as `session.createSQLQuery( ... )`.   I'm still scratching my head as to whether truly mocking a sessionFactory within integration tests is actually possible.  All the above suggestions do not work for me