# Grails Integration test and session injection

Tags: session, grails, groovy, integration-testing

I have a problem with session and integration test. Here is what I tried.
I have a service called ShoppingCartWebshopService and it has the methode "createNewShoppableItem". This method calls two methods from PriceService and there is the problem.

Part of PriceService:

```
def sessionFactory_lookup
def getActionResult(){
final session = sessionFactory_lookup.currentSession.connection()
            def conn = new Sql(session)
{query and rest of the code}
}
```

Part of ShoppingCartWebshopService:

```
    def customerPriceDetails = priceService.getActionResult()
```

My integration test:

```
class ShoppingCartWebshopServiceIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def shoppingCartWebshopService
    def priceService
    def sessionFactory

    void "test something"() {
        when:
//First version of session injection:
//      ApplicationContext context = (ApplicationContext)        ServletContextHolder.getServletContext().getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT);
//      SessionFactory sf = context.getBean('sessionFactory')
//      Session session = sf.getCurrentSession()

    shoppingCartWebshopService.priceService = priceService
    shoppingCartWebshopService.priceService.getActionResult("003-65607758", "19")

//Second version of session injection:
       def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
//

        shoppingCartWebshopService.priceService.sessionFactory_lookup = session
        def artikl = shoppingCartWebshopService.createNewShoppableItem("003-65607758", "19")

        then:
        artikl.size() > 0

    }
}
```

The first version I found here but it doesn't work. [Grails integration test and sessionFactory.currentSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697726/grails-integration-test-and-sessionfactory-currentsession)

With first version I get his error: "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: currentSession for class: org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl"

With second version I get this: java.lang.NullPointerException: "Cannot get property 'currentSession' on null object" at the part in PriceService where I call session for sql query execution.

Please, could someone give me an advice because I don't know what to try anymore.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- Is sessionFactory_lookup a service/an auto-wired class?
- If its auto-wired is it preset in your resources.groovy / place where
  you declare all your beans that are not services?

I ask these since its returning a Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: SessionFactory_lookup isn't present in resources.groovy or other places in my app. I searched on google but there isn't much information. It maybe sounds weird but there is no definition for that bean. I'm using IntelliJ and there is no bean icon next to "def sessionFactory_lookup". Nevertheless it works ok for executing sql procedures.

Comment: I only found this article where sessionFactory_lookup is mentioned. http://totalprogus.blogspot.hr/2015/03/upgrade-grails-244-to-250.html It's about upgrading Grails to higher version.

Comment: Could you try changing the def sessionFactory_lookup to sessionFactory in your PriceService?

Comment: I failed to find a proper documentation for sessionFactory_lookup either. So I was wondering if they are both same type of objects or not since in your integ test you are assigning sessionFactory_lookup to session, but they both seem to have same methods on them as per your code.